# WSDLSOAP-ERROR: when accessing soap URL in browser

Tags: magento-1.7, api, soap, soap-api-v2

I am getting below error when accessing

> http://example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/

(main site URL renamed for security purpose)in browser.
Error is

> WSDLSOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Missing  with name
>   'typens:catalogProductAttributeRemoveRequest'

I am not sure why this is happening. Any kind of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Never mind. Solved.

Answer (score 1):

Some possible reasons:

- Some times cache just gone corrupted, just flush all caches and try again.
- Some extension is adding a syntax error that breaks the code before `typens:catalogProductAttributeRemoveRequest` definition. To verify try to disable all extensions, clear all caches and try again.
- Magento Soap api makes some requests to it self, so ensure that you have your domain pointing to 127.0.0.1 / 0.0.0.0 in your `/etc/hosts` files.

(Most times it's the second one)

Comment: Thanks Mauro for your suggestions. Let me go through. Will update.

Comment: Solved. Thanks for your suggestions though.